# How to generate Unique coupen code?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I am trying to generate coupen codes to provide discounts. I have tried with `Math.Random()` but I am not sure if it will assure an unique code each time ?.

Also I have tried with `dbms_random.string` utility of `Oracle' which is generating random numbers but it also does not guarantee the unique code.

Does anyone knows a good algorithm to do this ?

I am using java and oracle to develope the code.

**EDIT**: After looking few responses I would like to add that I have to store each and every generated code in the table. And the generated code should be Alphanumeric.

Comment: coupon code is stored in db?

Comment: can't simply create a sequence and use sequence number as coupon code?

Comment: @loki: I have to generate the coupen codes with sequences can be guessed easily. So any one can try with the next number and missue the coupen codes. Sequence is not a solution at all.

Comment: No, I don't think the above question is duplicate of my question.

Comment: I agree: the proposed thread is not a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Java [UUID class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). It generates random 128-bit alphanumeric strings. The possibility of repetition of a string is astronomically low.

Specifically:

```
import java.util.UUID
.
.
String uniqueString = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
.
.
```

Comment: Not sure why this hasn't been accepted.  UUID generates something like 32 alphanumeric values, so the probability of getting a collision is (1/(26 (letters)+ 10 (numbers))^(32))^2=(1/(36^32))^2.... you're never going to get a collision.

Comment: Unique?  Certainly.  Depending on whether this is in a store or on-line (where copy/paste is an option), it may be a bit long to type in for a coupon code.

Answer (score 1):

Random is random, but you correctly identified this doesn't mean unique.

You will need to store somewhere (like back in your database) the codes that have been used, and then scan the records when you create a new code.

Realistically, you might want to generate a 100 (or a 1000, or 10,000) coupons up front, store them, and assign them out as required.

Comment: First thing I am stroing the codes in table, but rechecking the existing code is not prefferable at all, because we have to generate the coupen in batches.

Answer (score 1):

I would combine random number + sequence number. That gives you a random number that is unique because the sequence number is unique.

Otherwise you need to do a trial-and-error approach. Maybe in advance to save run-time. Suppose you have a table "coupon-keys" with a unique index coupon_id. You generate the random key and then insert it. You catch the insert failure if not unique and retry until you have enough coupon keys generated. Additionally you have a column "used" and each time you give out a coupon you update the column to keep track of what coupon numbers are still available.

Comment: That won't guarantee uniqueness.  For example, random numbers 1234,  1233 issued in sequence 10051, 10052 would collide (11285==11285).  If you mean to convert them to strings and concatenate, then "123"+"456" could collide with "12"+"3456".

Comment: The first method wouldn't guarantee uniqueness, but I think the second one would work fine.

Comment: Yes I meant something like fixed length random numbers left padded with zeros concatenated. But that is just the quick trick, really. Now after one day of answering this I must admit that I think the solution I personally would like the most is the generate and insert retry if failed loop method. If the random number is long enough it should not be so many trials.

Comment: This is a nice trick to generate unique. Even if we have last 4 characters as part of sequence and if it is alpanumeric we can generate 36^4 coupons ie 1679616. and if the alphanumeric is both lower and upper case then 62^4 combinations can be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of alphanumeric characters that represent all valid characters for your coupon codes.  Let's say it's all upper and lower-cased alpha characters.

```
String chars[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
```

You can convert any integer to a shorter code, basically by performing a number base conversion (albeit in reverse order).

```
int max=100000000;
int random=(int) (Math.random()*max);
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
while (random>0) {
    sb.append(chars[random % chars.length]);
    random /= chars.length;
}
String couponCode=sb.toString();
```

So, generate a random number, shorten it to a string, and insert it into your database.  If the insert fails due to collision, then retry.  Collisions should be fairly rare, and would only have a minimal cost when they occur.  Your coupon codes should remain short and easy to key in.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle from 10g up has the dbms_crypto package included to allow the generation of genuinely random sequences.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#i1000605 .

Having obtained some random RAW bytes, these can then be encoded into an suitable alpha-numeric string using the utl_encode package.

http://psoug.org/reference/utl_encode.html

If coupon codes are long enough, collisions should be infeasible, but you could still wrap the coupon creation in a PL/SQL function to handle any collisions. Eg. use a UNIQUE constraint and catch the exception if the INSERT fails. (As Bob Jarvis suggested.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestions:

Your table should look something like

```
CREATE TABLE COUPONS
  (COUPON_CODE NUMBER
     CONSTRAINT PK_COUPONS
       PRIMARY KEY
       USING INDEX);        -- plus whatever other fields you need
```

Your code to generate unique codes should be something like

```
DECLARE
  nCoupon_code    NUMBER;
  bCode_unique     BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  bCode_unique := FALSE;

  WHILE bCode_unique = FALSE LOOP
    BEGIN
      nCoupon_code := GENERATE_COUPON_CODE;  -- function to generate a coupon code

      INSERT INTO COUPONS (COUPON_CODE)
        VALUES (nCoupon_code);

      bCode_unique := TRUE;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        NULL;  -- Fall through, loop back to the top, generate new code, continue
    END;
  END LOOP;  -- bCode_unique
END;
```

What goes on here is that the program first set the 'code unique' flag to FALSE, indicating that a unique code has not yet been generated.  A loop is then entered, and will continue as long as the 'code unique' flag is still FALSE.  A coupon code is then generated and stored into the database.  If the code is unique all will be well, the 'code unique' flag will be set, and the loop will be exited.  HOWEVER, if the code is NOT unique the INSERT statement will fail with a DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception.  This will happen because COUPON_CODE is the primary key on the COUPONS table, and we know that a primary key has three attributes: it must be non-NULL, if must never change, and it MUST BE UNIQUE.  (For our purposes here we could have used a UNIQUE constraint on COUPONS.COUPON_CODE and gotten the same effect).  If the DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX exception is thrown because the coupon code generated is not unique the exception handler will be entered where the code will do absolutely nothing; that is, the 'code unique' flag will remain FALSE, the code will drop out of the exception handler, and because the 'code unique' flag is still FALSE the loop will start over again where another code will be generated, and etc, etc, etc, until a unique code is finally generated and the INSERT succeeds.

This may seem like a lot of work, but if the coupon code generation algorithm is chosen well it won't generate a lot of collisions and thus won't have to loop too often.  IMO this is a reasonable solution considering the environment - in PL/SQL you count on using the database to do some of the heavy lifting, like guaranteeing uniqueness.  You can spend a ton of time trying to come up with the One True Code Generation Algorithm Which Will Never, Ever Possibly Generate A Duplicate, or you can just come up with something that's good-if-not-perfect and work with the database to make sure that the codes which are finally chosen end up unique.  YMMV.  And implementing the One True Algorithm can be a lot of fun, if not a particularly good use of time.  :-)

Share and enjoy.